# Gzipping in a AWS Lambda function served through API Gateway V2 throws ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED on the browser

Tags: node.js, express, aws-lambda, gzip, aws-api-gateway

I want to serve gzipped content through AWS Gateway V2. Unfortunately, AWS Gateway V2 has no compression functionality out of the box, so I'm doing the compression on the lambda before I send it through the wire.

The problem is that after all the setup the requests are failing with `ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED`. It's working fine when I run the endpoints locally, so I know that the functionality works in my development server. What do I need to do to get API Gateway V2 to understand not to touch this response and just send it through as-is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After many hours I'm now serving gzipped React SSR content through AWS Lambda successfully. Here's what I figured out and I hope save someone some time in the future.

The fact that API Gateway V2 has no option to compress responses at AWS's side is intentional. AWS Gateway V2 is cheaper than AWS Gateway, and it's because there's simply less features. In fact AWS Gateway V2 is significantly simpler than V1 and will mostly stay out of your way.

If you're using an AWS library to "proxy" your server to the lambda function, you'll need to make sure of the following:

## `isBase64Encoded` is returned as a property from the lambda

`isBase64Encoded` instructs AWS to not apply any kind of rules on the data you're serving and just "pass it through". Because it's `base64` encoded, AWS can simply decode the string and serve the raw decoded data to the client. This means that other types of compression, such as Brotli, can get served with no problem. Please keep in mind that you'll need to properly set your `Content` headers appropriate.

## The `body` is compressed AND encoded in base64

This part is particularly important; you might be sending the data through the wire as binary data, and thus when AWS tries to parse it again, it becomes garbage and gets served directly to the browser.

One thing you can do is run your lambda in SAM locally and see what it returns. This is how I was able to figure out that the data being sent over the wire to AWS was compressed, but it was in the wrong data format (it was just string garbage and not encoded properly when I `console.log`'d it). When you run it through SAM, the response should be a `base64` encoded string.

## A few more notes regarding `aws-serverless-express` or any equivalent

If you're using a library to proxy your Node server to API Gateway V2, make sure you read through the source code and understand how it works. In my case, I needed to capture the result that is returned by the promise that is exposed by this library and then add the `isBase64Encoded` prop (which should be `true` in these scenarios).

Another thing I did to make sure that I could distinguish base64 encoded content over regular UTF-8 content is that I added a header to the response named `x-base64-content` and I set it to `true`, so that I could read this header in the lambda function and then pass in `isBase64Encoded`. This also gives me the ability to just pass in normal data from the server if I ever decide to. Because this header is not relevant to the client, I made sure to delete it afterwards.

I hope this helps someone who is going on this journey of serving compressed content through AWS Lambda and API Gateway V2.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer. I've a question: i created an API and a lambda with serverless using aws-serverless-express as proxy. The AWS Api gateway i'm using is V1 right? How can i check?

Thank you very much

Comment: @MajinDageta AWS API Gateway is mostly now V2. You should probably disregard any documentation for V1.